# How to Make Plot Show up?

Tags: python, user-interface, matplotlib, tkinter

So I am trying to create this function to make a plot of a mass spring damper system and we should be able to basically change whatever we like, the values for the function and the sliders should affect the plot as well, i'm having trouble trying to get my function plotted. The error is coming within the function where I am trying to use my solveMBK function inside my PlotWindow function, I am not sure how to include the values from my sliders as well as the other values that are inputted in the start up window. Here is a look at my code:

```
import tkinter as tk

from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import (FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk)

from matplotlib.figure import Figure

import numpy as np


def solveMBK(inlist):

    x0 = inlist[0]
    dx0 = inlist[1]
    dt = inlist[2]
    m = inlist[3]
    b = inlist[4]
    k = inlist[5]
    tf = inlist[6]
    Z = inlist[7]

    t = np.arange(0,tf,dt)

    z0 = np.zeros_like(t)
    z1 = np.zeros_like(t)

    z0[0] = x0
    z1[0] = dx0

    for c in range(len(t)-1):
        z0[c+1] = z0[c] + z1[c]*dt
        z1[c+1] = z1[c] + ((ABradiobutton(Z,t[c]) - k*z0[c] - b*z1[c]) / m)

    x = z0

    return t,x

def ABradiobutton(Z, t):
    if Z == 1:
        A = float(A_entry.get())
        return A

    elif Z == 2:
        B = float(B_entry.get())
        return np.sin(B*t)

def PlotWindow():

    root1 = tk.Tk()

    root1.title("Plot")

    Mmin = float(Mmin_entry.get())

    Mmax = float(Mmax_entry.get())

    bmin = float(bmin_entry.get())

    bmax = float(bmax_entry.get())

    kmin = float(kmin_entry.get())

    kmax = float(kmax_entry.get())

    mscale = tk.Scale(root1, from_=Mmin, to=Mmax, label="m", bd=2, length=200, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, command = funcPlot)

    mscale.set((Mmin+Mmax)/2)

    mscale.grid(row=1, column=0)

    bscale = tk.Scale(root1, from_=bmin, to=bmax, label="b", bd=2, length=200, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, command = funcPlot)

    bscale.set((bmin+bmax)/2)

    bscale.grid(row=3, column=0)

    kscale = tk.Scale(root1, from_=kmin, to=kmax, label="k", bd=2, length=200, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, command = funcPlot)

    kscale.set((kmin+kmax)/2)

    kscale.grid(row=5, column=0)

    tk.Label(root1, text = " ").grid(row=6, column=0)

    tk.Button(root1, text="Back", command=root1.destroy).grid(row=7, column=0)

    Graph_Frame = tk.Frame(root1)

    Graph_Frame.grid(row=2, column=2, columnspan=10, rowspan=10)

    Fig = Figure(figsize=(5.5,4))

    a = Fig.add_subplot(111)

    if Radio_Var == 1:
        t,x = solveMBK(str(mscale.get()), str(bscale.get()), str(kscale.get()), str(A_entry.get()), str(x0_Entry.get()), str(dxdt_Entry.get()), str(tfinal_entry.get()), str(dt_entry.get()))
        a.plot(t,x)

    # elif Radio_Var == 2:
    #     t,x = solveMBK()
    #     a.plot(t,x)

    tk.Label(Graph_Frame, text = "Mass-Spring-Damper Plot").pack()

    canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(Fig, Graph_Frame)

    canvas.draw()

    canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()

    toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(canvas, Graph_Frame)

    toolbar.update()

    canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()



def CloseWindow():

    root.quit()

    root.destroy()

    exit()


def funcPlot(input_list, mscale, bscale, kscale, a, canvas, event=None):
    input_list[0]=float(x0_Entry.get())
    input_list[1]=float(dxdt_Entry.get())
    input_list[2]=float(dt_entry.get())
    input_list[3]=float(mscale.get())
    input_list[4]=float(bscale.get())
    input_list[5]=float(kscale.get())
    input_list[6]=float(tfinal_entry.get())
    input_list[7]=float(Radio_Var.get())

    data = solveMBK(input_list)

    a.plot(data[0], data[1])

    canvas.draw()

    return

root = tk.Tk()

root.title("Numerical solution of a second order differential equation")

tk.Label(root, text = "Differential Equation:").grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.E)

tk.Label(root, text = "m d2x/dt2 + b dx/dt + kx = f(x)").grid(row=0, column=1)

x0_Start = tk.IntVar()

x0_Start.set("0")

x0_Entry = tk.Entry(root, width=7, textvariable = x0_Start)

tk.Label(root, text = "x(0) = ").grid(row=1, column=0, stick=tk.E), x0_Entry.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=tk.W)

dxdt_Start = tk.IntVar()

dxdt_Start.set("0")

dxdt_Entry = tk.Entry(root, width=7, textvariable = dxdt_Start)

tk.Label(root, text = "dx(0)/dt= ").grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=tk.E), dxdt_Entry.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=tk.W)

A_start = tk.IntVar()

A_start.set("1")

A_entry = tk.Entry(root, width=7, textvariable = A_start)

tk.Label(root, text = "A = ").grid(row=6, column=1, sticky=tk.E), A_entry.grid(row=6, column=2, sticky=tk.W)

B_start = tk.IntVar()

B_start.set("0")

B_entry = tk.Entry(root, width=7, textvariable=B_start)

tk.Label(root, text= "B =").grid(row=7,column=1, sticky=tk.E), B_entry.grid(row=7, column=2, sticky=tk.W)

tk.Label(root, text = " ").grid(row=5, column=0, sticky=tk.E)

Radio_Var = tk.IntVar()

tk.Radiobutton(root, text="A", value = 1, variable=Radio_Var).grid(row=6, column=1, sticky = tk.W)

tk.Radiobutton(root, text="sin(Bt)", value = 2, variable=Radio_Var).grid(row=7, column=1, sticky = tk.W)

Radio_Var.set(1)

tk.Label(root, text = "f(x) = ").grid(row=6, column=0, sticky=tk.E)

tk.Label(root, text = " ").grid(row=8, column=0, sticky=tk.E)

tfinal_start = tk.IntVar()

tfinal_start.set("10")

tfinal_entry = tk.Entry(root, width = 7, textvariable=tfinal_start)

tk.Label(root, text = "tfinal = ").grid(row=9, column=0, sticky=tk.E), tfinal_entry.grid(row=9, column=1, sticky=tk.W)

dt_start = tk.IntVar()

dt_start.set("0.001")

dt_entry = tk.Entry(root, width = 7, textvariable=dt_start)

tk.Label(root, text = "dt = ").grid(row=9, column=1, sticky=tk.E), dt_entry.grid(row=9, column=2, sticky=tk.W)

tk.Label(root, text = " ").grid(row=10, column=0, sticky=tk.E)

Mmin_start = tk.IntVar()

Mmin_start.set("1")

Mmin_entry = tk.Entry(root, width=7, textvariable=Mmin_start)

tk.Label(root, text = "Mmin = ").grid(row=11, column=0, sticky=tk.E), Mmin_entry.grid(row=11, column=1, sticky=tk.W)

Mmax_start = tk.IntVar()

Mmax_start.set("100")

Mmax_entry = tk.Entry(root, width=7, textvariable=Mmax_start)

tk.Label(root, text = "Mmax = ").grid(row=11,column=1, sticky=tk.E), Mmax_entry.grid(row=11, column=2, sticky=tk.W)

bmin_start = tk.IntVar()

bmin_start.set("1")

bmin_entry = tk.Entry(root, width=7, textvariable=bmin_start)

tk.Label(root, text = "bmin = ").grid(row=12, column=0, sticky=tk.E), bmin_entry.grid(row=12, column=1, sticky=tk.W)

bmax_start = tk.IntVar()

bmax_start.set("250")

bmax_entry = tk.Entry(root, width=7, textvariable=bmax_start)

tk.Label(root, text= "bmax = ").grid(row=12, column=1, sticky=tk.E), bmax_entry.grid(row=12,column=2,sticky=tk.W)

kmin_start = tk.IntVar()

kmin_start.set("1")

kmin_entry = tk.Entry(root, width=7, textvariable=kmin_start)

tk.Label(root, text= "kmin = ").grid(row=13, column=0, sticky=tk.E), kmin_entry.grid(row=13, column=1, sticky=tk.W)

kmax_start = tk.IntVar()

kmax_start.set("500")

kmax_entry = tk.Entry(root, width=7, textvariable=kmax_start)

tk.Label(root, text="kmax = ").grid(row=13, column=1, sticky=tk.E), kmax_entry.grid(row=13, column=2, sticky=tk.W)

tk.Button(root, text = "Quit", command=CloseWindow, width=10).grid(row=14, column=0)

tk.Button(root, text= "Plot", command=PlotWindow, width=10).grid(row=14, column=3)

root.mainloop()
```

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Either you show it inline, or you call `pyplot.show()`

Comment: That isnt the problem with the code...

Answer (score 0):

You're passing `funcPlot` as the `command` for `Scale` to call:

```
mscale = tk.Scale(root1, ..., command=funcPlot)
```

According to the documentation, `command` is:

> A procedure to be called every time the slider is moved. This
>   procedure will be passed *one* argument, the new scale value.

But instead of taking *one* argument, your `funcPlot()` function requires *six* arguments:

```
def funcPlot(input_list, mscale, bscale, kscale, a, canvas, event=None):
```

Which leads to the error:

```
TypeError: funcPlot() missing 5 required positional arguments: 'mscale', 'bscale', 'kscale', 'a', and 'canvas'
```

You need to rethink how this is supposed to work.  Below is my rework of your code.  I got around the problem above by using global variables -- I'm not proud of that.  I also had to rework the way your plot gets embedded in Tk as what you had wasn't working:

```
import tkinter as tk
import numpy as np

from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import (FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk)
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

def solveMBK(inlist):

    x0, dx0, dt, m, b, k, tf, Z = inlist

    t = np.arange(0, tf, dt)

    z0 = np.zeros_like(t)
    z1 = np.zeros_like(t)

    z0[0] = x0
    z1[0] = dx0

    for c in range(len(t) - 1):
        z0[c + 1] = z0[c] + z1[c] * dt
        z1[c + 1] = z1[c] + ((ABradiobutton(Z, t[c]) - k * z0[c] - b * z1[c]) / m)

    return t, z0

def ABradiobutton(Z, t):

    if Z == 1:
        A = float(A_entry.get())
        return A

    if Z == 2:
        B = float(B_entry.get())
        return np.sin(B * t)

def PlotWindow():
    global mscale, bscale, kscale, subplot, figure_canvas

    plot_window = tk.Toplevel(root)
    plot_window.title("Plot")

    Mmin = float(Mmin_entry.get())
    Mmax = float(Mmax_entry.get())

    bmin = float(bmin_entry.get())
    bmax = float(bmax_entry.get())

    kmin = float(kmin_entry.get())
    kmax = float(kmax_entry.get())

    mscale = tk.Scale(plot_window, from_=Mmin, to=Mmax, label="m", bd=2, length=200, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, command=funcPlot)
    mscale.set((Mmin + Mmax) / 2)
    mscale.grid(row=1, column=0)

    bscale = tk.Scale(plot_window, from_=bmin, to=bmax, label="b", bd=2, length=200, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, command=funcPlot)
    bscale.set((bmin + bmax) / 2)
    bscale.grid(row=3, column=0)

    kscale = tk.Scale(plot_window, from_=kmin, to=kmax, label="k", bd=2, length=200, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, command=funcPlot)
    kscale.set((kmin + kmax) / 2)
    kscale.grid(row=5, column=0)

    tk.Label(plot_window, text=" ").grid(row=6, column=0)

    tk.Button(plot_window, text="Back", command=plot_window.destroy).grid(row=7, column=0)

    graph_frame = tk.Frame(plot_window)
    graph_frame.grid(row=2, column=2, columnspan=10, rowspan=10)

    figure = Figure(figsize=(5.5, 4))

    subplot = figure.add_subplot(111)

    if Radio_Var.get() == 1:
        t, x = solveMBK([float(mscale.get()), float(bscale.get()), float(kscale.get()), float(A_entry.get()), float(x0_Entry.get()), float(dxdt_Entry.get()), float(tfinal_entry.get()), float(dt_entry.get())])
        subplot.plot(t, x)

    # elif Radio_Var.get() == 2:
    #   t, x = solveMBK()
    #   subplot.plot(t, x)

    figure_canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(figure, master=graph_frame)
    figure_canvas.draw()
    figure_canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)

    toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(figure_canvas, graph_frame)
    toolbar.update()
    figure_canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)

    tk.Label(graph_frame, text="Mass-Spring-Damper Plot").pack()

def CloseWindow():
    root.quit()
    root.destroy()
    exit()

def funcPlot(event):
    input_list = []

    input_list.append(float(x0_Entry.get()))
    input_list.append(float(dxdt_Entry.get()))
    input_list.append(float(dt_entry.get()))
    input_list.append(float(mscale.get()))
    input_list.append(float(bscale.get()))
    input_list.append(float(kscale.get()))
    input_list.append(float(tfinal_entry.get()))
    input_list.append(float(Radio_Var.get()))

    t, x = solveMBK(input_list)

    subplot.plot(t, x)

    figure_canvas.draw()

figure_canvas = subplot = mscale = bscale = kscale = None

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Numerical solution of a second order differential equation")

tk.Label(root, text="Differential Equation:").grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.E)
tk.Label(root, text="m d2x/dt2 + b dx/dt + kx = f(x)").grid(row=0, column=1)

tk.Label(root, text="x(0) = ").grid(row=1, column=0, stick=tk.E)

x0_Start = tk.IntVar()
x0_Start.set("0")
x0_Entry = tk.Entry(root, width=7, textvariable=x0_Start)
x0_Entry.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=tk.W)

tk.Label(root, text="dx(0)/dt = ").grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=tk.E)

dxdt_Start = tk.IntVar()
dxdt_Start.set("0")
dxdt_Entry = tk.Entry(root, width=7, textvariable=dxdt_Start)
dxdt_Entry.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=tk.W)

tk.Label(root, text=" ").grid(row=5, column=0, sticky=tk.E)

Radio_Var = tk.IntVar()
Radio_Var.set(1)
tk.Label(root, text="f(x) = ").grid(row=6, column=0, sticky=tk.E)
tk.Radiobutton(root, text="A", value=1, variable=Radio_Var).grid(row=6, column=1, sticky=tk.W)
tk.Label(root, text="A = ").grid(row=6, column=1, sticky=tk.E)

A_start = tk.IntVar()
A_start.set("1")
A_entry = tk.Entry(root, width=7, textvariable=A_start)
A_entry.grid(row=6, column=2, sticky=tk.W)

tk.Radiobutton(root, text="sin(Bt)", value=2, variable=Radio_Var).grid(row=7, column=1, sticky=tk.W)
tk.Label(root, text="B =").grid(row=7, column=1, sticky=tk.E)

B_start = tk.IntVar()
B_start.set("0")
B_entry = tk.Entry(root, width=7, textvariable=B_start)
B_entry.grid(row=7, column=2, sticky=tk.W)

tk.Label(root, text=" ").grid(row=8, column=0, sticky=tk.E)

tk.Label(root, text="tfinal = ").grid(row=9, column=0, sticky=tk.E)

tfinal_start = tk.IntVar()
tfinal_start.set("10")
tfinal_entry = tk.Entry(root, width=7, textvariable=tfinal_start)
tfinal_entry.grid(row=9, column=1, sticky=tk.W)

tk.Label(root, text="dt = ").grid(row=9, column=1, sticky=tk.E)

dt_start = tk.IntVar()
dt_start.set("0.001")
dt_entry = tk.Entry(root, width=7, textvariable=dt_start)
dt_entry.grid(row=9, column=2, sticky=tk.W)

tk.Label(root, text=" ").grid(row=10, column=0, sticky=tk.E)

tk.Label(root, text="Mmin = ").grid(row=11, column=0, sticky=tk.E)

Mmin_start = tk.IntVar()
Mmin_start.set("1")
Mmin_entry = tk.Entry(root, width=7, textvariable=Mmin_start)
Mmin_entry.grid(row=11, column=1, sticky=tk.W)

tk.Label(root, text="Mmax = ").grid(row=11, column=1, sticky=tk.E)

Mmax_start = tk.IntVar()
Mmax_start.set("100")
Mmax_entry = tk.Entry(root, width=7, textvariable=Mmax_start)
Mmax_entry.grid(row=11, column=2, sticky=tk.W)

tk.Label(root, text="bmin = ").grid(row=12, column=0, sticky=tk.E)

bmin_start = tk.IntVar()
bmin_start.set("1")
bmin_entry = tk.Entry(root, width=7, textvariable=bmin_start)
bmin_entry.grid(row=12, column=1, sticky=tk.W)

tk.Label(root, text="bmax = ").grid(row=12, column=1, sticky=tk.E)

bmax_start = tk.IntVar()
bmax_start.set("250")
bmax_entry = tk.Entry(root, width=7, textvariable=bmax_start)
bmax_entry.grid(row=12, column=2, sticky=tk.W)

tk.Label(root, text="kmin = ").grid(row=13, column=0, sticky=tk.E)

kmin_start = tk.IntVar()
kmin_start.set("1")
kmin_entry = tk.Entry(root, width=7, textvariable=kmin_start)
kmin_entry.grid(row=13, column=1, sticky=tk.W)

tk.Label(root, text="kmax = ").grid(row=13, column=1, sticky=tk.E)

kmax_start = tk.IntVar()
kmax_start.set("500")
kmax_entry = tk.Entry(root, width=7, textvariable=kmax_start)
kmax_entry.grid(row=13, column=2, sticky=tk.W)

tk.Button(root, text="Quit", command=CloseWindow, width=10).grid(row=14, column=0)
tk.Button(root, text="Plot", command=PlotWindow, width=10).grid(row=14, column=3)

root.mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: @Thomas, I did just enough rework of your code to get it to turn over and added to my answer.  My guess is that it still needs additional work.  I don't know much about Matplotlib -- I just followed the documentation and examples.